# Pandas : Extend rows based on column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, loops

I have one list of list dataset :

```
data_set = [['note_a', 'mix'],['note_b', 'mix'], ['mix','leave','note_a','note_b','random'],['mix','random','note_a','note_b']]
```

I am taking the cartesian product of it :

```
import itertools
all_method = pd.DataFrame(itertools.product(*data_set))
all_method
```

Output

```
         0       1       2       3
0   note_a  note_b     mix     mix
1   note_a  note_b     mix  random
2   note_a  note_b     mix  note_a
3   note_a  note_b     mix  note_b
4   note_a  note_b   leave     mix
..     ...     ...     ...     ...
75     mix     mix  note_b  note_b
76     mix     mix  random     mix
77     mix     mix  random  random
78     mix     mix  random  note_a
79     mix     mix  random  note_b

[80 rows x 4 columns]
```

Now I want to extend each mix value with three new values :

```
mix = ['copy_a', 'copy_b', 'copy_c']
```

So if there is mix in a row, it should extend three rows and replace mix with each of this value.

Example of three rows what I am looking :

```
[('note_a', 'note_b', 'copy_a', 'copy_a'), ('note_a', 'note_b', 'copy_b', 'copy_b'), ('note_a', 'note_b', 'copy_c','copy_c'),
 ('note_a', 'note_b', 'copy_a', 'random'), ('note_a', 'note_b', 'copy_b', 'random'), ('note_a', 'note_b', 'copy_c', 'random'),
 ('note_a', 'note_b', 'copy_a', 'note_a'), ('note_a', 'note_b', 'copy_b', 'note_a'), ('note_a', 'note_b', 'copy_c', 'note_a')]
```

In the first row, there are two 'mix' so it's extending three rows filling 'copy_a' with 'mix' then 'copy_b' with 'mix' and at last 'copy_c' with the 'mix'.

> What I've tried :

```
import itertools
all_method = list(itertools.product(*data_set))
all_method


def extend_rows_func(data):
    extend_rows = []
    mix         = ['copy_a', 'copy_b', 'copy_c']
    for i in data:
        if 'mix' in i:
            for copy_op in mix: 
                extend_rows.append([copy_op if x== 'mix' else x for x in i])
        else:
            extend_rows.append(list(i))
    return extend_rows
```

Is there any optimized or pandas way to do this without using three loops?

Comment: It is hard, since it is related to cell explode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider `replace` then `concat`:

```
pd.concat(all_method.replace('mix',copy) for copy in ['copy_a', 'copy_b', 'copy_c'])
```

Output:

```
         0       1       2       3
0   note_a  note_b  copy_a  copy_a
1   note_a  note_b  copy_a  random
2   note_a  note_b  copy_a  note_a
3   note_a  note_b  copy_a  note_b
4   note_a  note_b   leave  copy_a
..     ...     ...     ...     ...
75  copy_c  copy_c  note_b  note_b
76  copy_c  copy_c  random  copy_c
77  copy_c  copy_c  random  random
78  copy_c  copy_c  random  note_a
79  copy_c  copy_c  random  note_b

[240 rows x 4 columns]
```

If you want to arrange the *original* rows together, you can chain that with `sort_index()`:

```
(pd.concat(all_method.replace('mix',copy) 
               for copy in ['copy_a', 'copy_b', 'copy_c'])
   .sort_index()
)
```

Output:

```
         0       1       2       3
0   note_a  note_b  copy_a  copy_a
0   note_a  note_b  copy_b  copy_b
0   note_a  note_b  copy_c  copy_c
1   note_a  note_b  copy_a  random
1   note_a  note_b  copy_b  random
..     ...     ...     ...     ...
78  copy_a  copy_a  random  note_a
78  copy_b  copy_b  random  note_a
79  copy_b  copy_b  random  note_b
79  copy_a  copy_a  random  note_b
79  copy_c  copy_c  random  note_b

[240 rows x 4 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice this method take time to run

```
mid=all_method.replace('mix',','.join(['copy_a', 'copy_b', 'copy_c'])).applymap(lambda x: x.split(','))

def unnesting_cell(df):

        explode = df.columns[df.iloc[0].str.len()>1]
        if len(explode) == 0 :
            return df
        else:
            df1 = pd.concat([
                pd.DataFrame({x: np.concatenate(df[x].values)}) for x in explode], axis=1)
            df1.index=df.index.tolist()*len(df1)
            return df1.join(df.drop(explode, 1).apply(lambda x : x.str[0] , axis=1), how='left')

df = pd.concat([unnesting_cell(mid.loc[[x]]) for x in mid.index])
```